# PHP - Form - show results on next page including selected link

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple form where I want users to select items and those items appear on the results page.  The items also include a link.  I would like the link to be included on the results page too.  Right now, I click on a check box with a link and the link does not appear on the results page.  Not sure where to go from here.

```
<html>
<body>
    Teaching Tools<br><br>
    Testing version only<br><br>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Building: <input type=“text” name=“bldg”><br><br><br>
        Teaching Tools:<br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="videos[]" value="Word"><label><a
                href="http://www.bluevalleyk12.org">Word</a></label><br /><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="videos[]" value="Padlet"> <label>Padlet</label><br />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Results Page:

```
<html>
<body>
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Email: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br><br>
    Your building: <?php echo $_POST[“bldg”]; ?><br><br>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // to run PHP script on submit
            if(!empty($_POST['videos'])) {
                // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
                foreach($_POST['videos'] as $selected) {
                    echo $selected."</br>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
  <br><br>Testing Mode<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a link as a checkbox label makes no sense. What do you want to happen: the check box is checked; or the browser goes to the the linked page ?

Comment: you can do some jquery stuff to do so otherwise not possible normally

Comment: The URL for the link would have to be the value of the input, then it could be posted to the second page. *No jQuery needed @anantkumarsingh*

Comment: oh thats what is wanted - should of guessed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the link from the form and add this instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="link" value="http://www.bluevalleyk12.org">
```

On `welcome.php` get the value of `link` with :

```
$link = $_POST["link"];
```

---

If you want to hide the link use [type="hidden"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp):

```
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="http://www.bluevalleyk12.org">
```

---

Finally, if you want the link visible but non editable, use [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="link" value="http://www.bluevalleyk12.org" readonly>
```